# Prevent DLL from being injected twice

Tags: c++, dll

Im making a DLL in c++ that is injected into another program.
When injecting more than once the program crashes so I want the DLL to first check if it was already injected and if so it will do some code like showing a message box or just quitting

Comment: Review what you are doing in the dll attach code. Unless you generate the dll's module name on the fly, there's only one actual image loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using EnumProcessModules

```cpp
    BOOL isInjected() {
        const char ProcessName = "Process.exe"; 
        std::string DllName = "MyDll.dll"; 


        DWORD dwProcessId = NULL;
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return false;

        PROCESSENTRY32 pe{};
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe))
        {
            do
            {
                if (_tcsicmp(pe.szExeFile, _T(ProcessName)) == 0)
                {
                    dwProcessId = pe.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe));
        }

        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);

        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwProcessId);
        if (hProcess == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        HMODULE hMods[1024];
        DWORD cbNeeded;
        if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
        {
            int amount = 0;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
            {
                TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
                if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
                {
                    std::string str1 = szModName;

                    if (str1.find(DllName) != std::string::npos) amount++;
                }
            }
            if (amount >= 2) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```